# linux file permissions for fastcgi socket file and containing folder

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, fastcgi

I am trying to set up mod_fcgid on my server. Part of the requirement is that Apache needs to create a socket file for mod_fcgid.

I specified the folder for Apache to write the socket data to:

> /var/lock/apache2/fcgid

I then specified this file in my fcgid.conf file as follows:

> SocketPath
>   /var/lock/apache2/fcgid/sock

I then changed the owner of the folder to www-data (the apache user) and gave the onwer full permissions to the folder and its contents.

I was able to run my test fcgi app then.

When I rebooted the machine, I found that ownership of /var/lock/apache2/fcgid has been reset to root, and with permission reset to 700

I have the following questions:

- Is there something specific about the /var/lock folder? - why is the permissions being reset after a reboot?
- Should I move my socket file to another location (in case root automatically takes ownership of contents in this folder for security reasons?)

I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Use `/var/run` for socket files.

Comment: @gravity: were you having a guess?. I tried what you recommended (i.e. changing the folder containing the socket file), the fastcgi app worked, then when I rebooted the machine, the file permissions were reset back to root again - same as before.

Comment: @oompah: I wasn't having a guess; I was suggesting to use a more proper location than `/var/lock` (which usually only contains lockfiles).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, after using the "best practices" folder you recommended, the problem of root changing permissions remains. Do you know why that is? - as it is, I cannot current deply a fastcgi app on my server for this reason